# How do i code the "continuous last 6 months" of data in Netezza?

Tags: sql, netezza

I need a `WHERE` clause for the last 6 continuous months from the current date.

At the moment, all I have is the following:

```sql
where "APPTREQCREATIONDATE" > '2019-01-01 00:00:01'
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate explanation of what *you* mean by "continuous last 6 months" would all help.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
WHERE APPTREQCREATIONDATE >= now() - interval '6 months'
```

[Reference](http://dwgeek.com/netezza-interval-data-types-conversion-examples.html/)

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!